# How to replace multiple elements in a string with a single element?

Tags: python, python-3.x

for suppose if I have a list of unique elements,

```
list = [.......,'a','b','c',.....]
```

How to replace 'a','b' with 'd' such that it results,

```
list = [.....,'d','c'.....]
```

without any loops.

I have tried doing this, but it's not working.

```
list[list.index('a'):list.index('b')] = 'd'
```

Answer (score 2):

A slice `l[start:stop]` does not include the element at the `stop` position.

Your code is almost correct, you only need to add `1` to `list.index('b')`:

```
In [14]: l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']

In [15]: l[l.index('a'):l.index('b') + 1] = 'd',

In [16]: l
Out[16]: ['d', 'c', 'e']
```

Also: try to avoid using names of built-in functions and types as variable names.

Answer (score 0):

You can first join the list, then use `replace`:

```
l = ["a", "d", "c", "a", "b", "c", "e"] #example list
new_list = list(''.join(l).replace("abc", "dc"))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'e']
```

Comment: This works for one-character strings, but will it work for multi-character strings and non-string objects?

Comment: @vaultah since the OP specifically used single-character strings in his example and even posted is desired output in the same manner, I tailored my solution for single-character strings only.